# Animate d3 line with gradient along

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm drawing lines programatically using this as a model: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4163057

the result was exactly what i expected, but i'd like to animate its drawing.

if it was a normal line, i'd do something like:

```
var line = d3.select("g#" + value['id'])
  .datum(points)
.append("path")
  .attr("d", line)
  .attr("stroke", "#444")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .attr("fill", "none");   

var totalLength = line.node().getTotalLength();

line
  .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
  .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
  .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .ease("linear")
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
```

but when i try to apply this in the gradient, the animation goes in the wrong way (literally, since it resamples the line with little portions of it).

i tried to follow this other example (http://bl.ocks.org/rveciana/10743959), based on the first, but it just looks animated cause the points are very close to each other.

is there a way i can animated long lines?

here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g373h94e/

what i have: the line with a gradient
what i want: that this line with a gradient animates as the black line above it

Comment: Can you create a fiddle/plunkr? Are you trying to animate the fill effect? What do you mean by goes in the wrong way?

Comment: added a jsfiddle. what i mean about the wrong way: to make this gradient, the line is divided into many strokes in the other direction. so, it animate in the narrow side of the stroke, not through its length.